# Jquery ajax call assigned success val to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch some urls from the back-end and assign `data.Results` in `window.__env.{variable}` so I can use it anywhere in the application.

I have this code

```
(function(window){
window.__env = window.__env || {};
   $.ajax({
    url: './assets/js/config/config.json',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        let baseUrl = data.BaseApiUrl;
        workflowDefinition(baseUrl);
    }
 })

function workflowDefinition(baseUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + 'api/Management/Configurations?name=SaveWorkflowDefinition&name=WorkflowDefinition',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.Results && data.Results[0] && data.Results[0].Value) {
                window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition = data.Results[0].Value;
                console.log(window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition);
            }

            if (data && data.Results && data.Results[1].Value) {
                window.__env.getWorkflowDefinition = data.Results[1].Value;
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            var errorMessage = "Failed to contact Workflow Server, please contact your IT administrator";
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    })
}
}(this))
```

I can see that the console.log is printing when this loads it gives me the right URL, then I tried passing  `window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition` to say another file `xfunction.js` where I want to use `window.__env` but it gives me `undefined`.

However if I pass it like this without ajax call, it works fine.

```
(function(window){
window.__env = window.__env || {};
     window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition= 'www.mybaseurl.com/api/Management/';
   })
```

Can someone point out why its returning `undefined` when I pass it to `xfunction.js` when doing an ajax call?

Comment: *passing  `window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition` to say `xfunction.js` it gives me undefined.*  I didnt get this , what exactly is `xfunction.js` ?

Comment: its another file where I want to use `window.__env.`,

Comment: I am suspecting that, your trying to access the data before it is defined with a value. since your assigning the data asynchronously, there is no predefined time when this would happen.

Comment: Are you sure you tried to access `window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition` after the Ajax finished? I am not asking if you are accessing `window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition` after calling the function `workflowDefinition` but after the Asynchronous ajax finished loading. How are you making sure of that?

Comment: i would suggest you to use this ajax script within `xfunction.js` so that you can monitor the completion the ajax request using promise/deferred object, which is easy process to do

Comment: well the reason why I put the ajax call in a separate file is because I want to use it everywhere else when I require it. The it prints the `console.log(window.__env.saveWorkflowDefinition)` after the call, so I assumed its ready to be used also isn't that why that `if()` conditions are for it checks if the data is ready.

Comment: is there another way of achieving this without doing the call in `xfunction.js`? as I find it weird because I'm doing the same call (within the same `(function())` where my ajax above is) for another URL which I'm passing to another file but that seems to be working.

Comment: its good practice to avoid redundant code. you can just a create a  function which makes a generic ajax call & returning the promise object created by `$.ajax` something like this `return $.ajax({.....})`, then you can cal this method from `xfunction.js` and monitor its `deffered/promise` object and upon completion execute the respective login(success or error). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Answer (score 0):

Since your Ajax calls will only provide the response asynchronously, you cannot expect to have the response in the same synchronous execution context.

One idea to resolve this, is to abandon the idea to store the response in a global (window) property, but to store instead a promise, which you *do* get synchronously.

The code could look like this:

```
window.promiseWorkFlowDefinition = $.ajax({
        url: './assets/js/config/config.json',
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(function (data) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: data.BaseApiUrl + 'api/Management/Configurations?' 
                                 + 'name=SaveWorkflowDefinition&name=WorkflowDefinition',
            method: 'GET',
        })
    }).then(function (data) {
        return data && data.Results && (data.Results[0] && data.Results[0].Value 
                                     || data.Results[1] && data.Results[1].Value)
               || ('No Results[0 or 1].Value found in:\n' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function (error) {
        var errorMessage = 
               "Failed to contact Workflow Server, please contact your IT administrator";
        alert(errorMessage);
    });

// Other file:
window.promiseWorkFlowDefinition.then(function(saveWorkflowDefinition) {
    // Use saveWorkflowDefinition here. This is called asynchronously.
    // ...
});
```

Comment: its showing `Declration or statement expected and expected ;` when I put that line of code //Other file.

Comment: `window.promiseWorkFlowDefinition.then(saveWorkflowDefinition) {
    // Use saveWorkflowDefinition here. This is called asynchronously.
    // ...
});` this one is showing an error in the texteditor.

Comment: Fixed a syntax error in the last few lines: `function` was missing after  `then`.

Comment: then I can do something like `console.log(saveWorkflowDefinition‌)` within that line?

Comment: yeah I did try but still gave me `undefined`

Comment: Can you debug, and see what you get as `data` argument at each of the `then` callbacks?

Comment: I added a specific return string for when the data does not have `Result[0 or 1].Value`, which would otherwise give `undefined`. See updated code.